# Как проверить пароль с Rfc2898DeriveBytes шифрованием?

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x

```
public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        byte[] salt;
        byte[] buffer2;
        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));
        }
        using (var bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
        {
            salt = bytes.Salt;
            buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
        }
        var dst = new byte[0x31];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
    });
```

Каждый раз выдает разные хеши, но как тогда проверить два пароля один из базы где храниться хешированным этим методом и один с пользователя
даже переменные `salt` разные при каждом вызове

Этот код c# с сервера где не мы это делали, и нам на своем сервер на python\django нужно проверить посредством python полученный хеш с сервера на c#, для это я нашел либу [pbkdf2](https://pypi.org/project/pbkdf2/)

```
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2
import base64

password_hash=b"ACNLVsim8ADv4Su/8w4loeSwTw2yH2R3++Pvrfx5xlDGlx0cDRdQ9t0TLJd1a5pvZw=="
password = b"123456"

# Соль
origin_salt = base64.b64decode(password_hash)[1:16]
print(base64.b64encode(origin_salt))
# > I0tWyKbwAO/hK7/zDiWh

buffer1 = base64.b64decode(password_hash)[17:]
print(base64.b64encode(buffer1))
# > sE8Nsh9kd/vj7638ecZQxpcdHA0XUPbdEyyXdWuab2c=

current_password_hash = PBKDF2(password, origin_salt, 1000)

# Соль
print(base64.b64encode(current_password_hash._PBKDF2__salt))
# > I0tWyKbwAO/hK7/zDiWh


print(base64.b64encode(current_password_hash.read(49)[17:]))
# > 0lC99e4tV+JmXBbJal19YyS1h9+djY+dsBHo/j8KNb8=
```

выдает одинаковые значение при каждом вызове, не то что на c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# код каждый раз создает разный `salt` (случайный), по этому пароли каждый раз другие. Вам нужно прочесть первые 16 байт пароля с C# (здесь записан 
`salt`), и подставить в Python. Потом проверить оставшиеся 32 байта.

Comment: @MelisZhoroev Я не понимаю... `PBKDF2` функция выглядит так: `PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations)`, `C#` код генерирует случайную соль, и записывает ее в начало массива (начиная с позиции 1). Вам нужно взять эту соль и сгенерить пароль в питоне.

Comment: Измените а что вы имели ввиду под `Потом проверить оставшиеся 32 байта.` именно проверить с 17 до 49 байта от обоих сторон? пароль с c# и сгенерированный на питоне по соли с пароля c c#

Comment: @MelisZhoroev Да, эти 32 байта это и есть пароль, который нужно сверить в обеих сторон.

Comment: они не соответствует https://gist.github.com/ProgMeli/f757a9b20e68712d87cb9d5f03ffa48d

Comment: @MelisZhoroev сложно сказать в чем проблема, к либе на питоне даже документации нет. там точно первый параметр пароль, а второй соль?

Comment: да так, но последние 32 байта случайные у C#

Comment: @MelisZhoroev тогда вам нужно поотлаживать, попробовать запустить PBKDF2 с простыми параметрами, например, пароль=1 соль=1, итерации=1 и добиться такого же результата в c#.

Comment: Все получилось и на этот раз точно), спасибо вам, вы нам очень сильно помогли

Answer (score 0):

Все получилось, оказывается мы пытались взять 32 байта срезом, а надо было генерить только на 32 байт и этот сравнивать с buffer2 с с#
Спасибо большое @Zergatul

```
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2
import base64

password_hash = b"AFBYUNpzMbvIHJWLmleAXWITetOsWOuma+FuPdV7fXogYM/8CVKtGygqzoWam14YXg=="
password = b"123456"

# оригинальный Соль
salt64 = base64.b64decode(password_hash)[1:17]
print(base64.b64encode(salt64))
# > UFhQ2nMxu8gclYuaV4BdYg==

# оригинальный буфер
buffer1 = base64.b64decode(password_hash)[17:]
print(base64.b64encode(buffer1))
# > E3rTrFjrpmvhbj3Ve316IGDP/AlSrRsoKs6FmpteGF4=


key = PBKDF2(password, salt64).read(32) #
print(base64.b64encode(key))
# > E3rTrFjrpmvhbj3Ve316IGDP/AlSrRsoKs6FmpteGF4=
```